# No search results -> narrower search suggested

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

When I was searching for a question I had seen before on Stack Overflow, I mistyped and ended up with no search results. That's not the problem, the problem was the suggestion given by the search page:

(my original search was not for HURGA HURGA)

[image]

Why is it suggested that I narrow my search when no matches are returned? Are there any circumstances under which this will yield results?

Comment: This bugs me too

Comment: Because you weren't searching hard enough?

Comment: The strangest part is that it isn't some automatic search tips page, it's only displayed when you have no results.

Comment: Originally I thought that's why it was being shown (because it's not generally bad advice). But I've only ever seen it on the no results page.

Comment: If you add another word that isn't found, it'll suggest that you put them both in quotes to search for the phrase. ;)

Comment: @animuson, I'll add that

Comment: Maybe it's the devs trolling people who actually waste their time with the SE search functionality =P

Comment: @ajax333221: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=HURGA%20HURGA

Comment: @Dennis thanks for the link, now I understand what is all about

Comment: No repro: The **HURGA HURGA** in the screenshot is crimson. Any ideas why mine is blueish? – @Cake: You're only focusing on the negative. The proposed Google link at the bottom (http://www.google.com/search?q=site:stackoverflow.com/questions+HURGA+HURGA) finds a match.

Comment: @Dennis the new screenshot is from meta's search function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is no longer the case...we removed these now-crap suggestions given with AND search they are useless 100% of the time.  We will be adding some help for no-op searches in the near future to help the user see what's happening when they mess up a [usually advanced] search though.